# Using Clause IN for strings in a query

Tags: php, ms-access, pdo

I've a PDO connection to a **MDB database ACCESS**. (NO MYSQL).

I've to do a SELECT query (INNER JOIN TO 2 TABLES ) seach for array of provence (and other fields).

TABLE CTR

```
| ID | CTR  | PROVENCE_CODE |
--------------------
| 1  |  A1  | MI   |
--------------------
| 2  |  A2  | BO   |
--------------------
| 3  |  A3  | MI   |
--------------------
```

PROVENCE TABLE:

```
| ID | CODE | NAME |
--------------------
| 1  |  MI  | Milan|
--------------------
| 2  |  BO  | Bolog|
--------------------
...

| 110|  ZA  | Zaga |
--------------------
```

The search is done by PROVENCE.CODE, no ID, so at the moment i've this using LIKE (i'm search for exact value):

```
$sql = " SELECT * FROM CTR INNER JOIN PROVENCE ON ( CTR.PROVENCE_CODE = PROVENCE.CODE ) WHERE ( a list of other conditions ) AND ";

$sql .= "(";

foreach ( $provences as $provence ) {

  $sql .= "PROVENCE.CODE LIKE ? OR ";                       
  $vars[] = $provence;

}

$sql = rtrim($sql, " OR ");
$sql .= ")";

$s = $db->prepare($sql);
$s->execute($vars);
$ris= $s->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Query works well for a certain amount of PROVENCE....but if I insert all 110 in my query i get error QUERY TOO COMPLEX.

I tried changing in:

```
            $sql .= " AND ( PROVENCE.CODE IN (";

            foreach ( $provences as $provence ) {

                $sql .= "?', ";

                $vars[] = $provence;

            }

            $sql = rtrim($sql, ", ");
            $sql .= "))";
```

But i get unexpected result. for EXAMPLE if I insert only "MI", i get all 3 entries of CTR table instead 2 result expected. I don't know if it's a PDO problem for MDB access

This is the REAL query for my use: very long

```
string 'SELECT DISTINCT [05CTR].[05ID], [01Anagrafica].[01ID] FROM 95TipiPagamento RIGHT JOIN (((44Domini RIGHT JOIN (((07PacchettiServizi RIGHT JOIN 06Servizi ON [07PacchettiServizi].[07ID] = [06Servizi].[06Pacchetto]) RIGHT JOIN ((04Tipicontratti RIGHT JOIN ((02Tipicontatti RIGHT JOIN (01Anagrafica LEFT JOIN 03ContattiAnagrafica ON [01Anagrafica].[01ID] = [03ContattiAnagrafica].[03Anagrafica]) ON [02Tipicontatti].[02ID] = [03ContattiAnagrafica].[03Tipocontatto]) RIGHT JOIN 05CTR ON [01Anagrafica].[01ID] = [05CTR].[05Anagrafica]) ON [04Tipicontratti].[04ID] = [05CTR].[05Contratto]) LEFT JOIN 08CodiciCTR ON [05CTR].[05ID] = [08CodiciCTR].[08CTR]) ON [06Servizi].[06ID] = [08CodiciCTR].[08Codice]) LEFT JOIN 45ElencoDomini ON [05CTR].[05ID] = [45ElencoDomini].[45IDcontratto]) ON [44Domini].[44ID] = [45ElencoDomini].[45IDdominio]) LEFT JOIN 47ConsulentiAssociati ON [05CTR].[05ID] = [47ConsulentiAssociati].[47IDContratto]) LEFT JOIN 24Pagamenti ON [05CTR].[05ID] = [24Pagamenti].[24Contratto]) ON [95TipiPagamento].[95ID] = [24Pagamenti].[24IDTipoPagamento] WHERE 1 AND (( [05CTR].[05Numerocontratto] LIKE ? OR [05CTR].[05Numerocontratto] LIKE ? ) OR ( [01Anagrafica].[01Ragionesociale] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Ragionesociale] LIKE ? ) OR ( [03ContattiAnagrafica].[03Contatto] LIKE ? OR [03ContattiAnagrafica].[03Contatto] LIKE ? )) AND ([01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ? OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ?)' (length=5790)

exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[22018]: Invalid character value for cast specification: -3030 [Microsoft][Driver ODBC Microsoft Access] Espressione troppo complessa (SQLExecute[-3030]
```

Comment: `echo $sql` before executing the query, and share the result. That way, we don't have to walk through your logic and guess what's going on, we can just see it.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth My query is too long. the problem occurs only using IN clause. I tried hardcode this piece of code: ... AND ( PROVENCE.CODE IN ( 'MI' ) ) but i get always unwanted results. So i think is a PDO problem (related to MDB access)?

Comment: There's no use guessing... Just share the query. PDO just passes the query off to Access over ODBC, so it's unlikely it's a PDO problem. _Query too complex_ is a common error in Access when you're doing weird stuff.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth added. I don't think it is usefull... the problem occur only if I insert a lot of variables....if I insert only few it works

Comment: Of course it will give "too complex" error. In generated SQL you have 118 `OR` conditions, 110 of them are the same - `OR [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] LIKE ?` Please check SQL generating logic.

Comment: @SergeyS. Yes it's the reason i tried using clause IN: [01Anagrafica].[01Provincia] IN (?, ?, ?, ...) but it seem to be ignored!

Comment: Ok i've solved. logic error on my CLAUSE IN